# elseif not working message doesn't show

Tags: php, if-statement, mysqli

`

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password']);

if (!preg_match("/^\w+$/",$username)) {
    $error = true;
    $username_error = "Username cant contain space and special characters";
}
if(strlen($password) < 6) {
    $error = true;
    $password_error = "Password must be minimum of 6 characters";
}

$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $username. "' and password = '" . md5($password) . "'");

if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $_SESSION['usr_id'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['usr_name'] = $row['name'];
if ($row['id'] == 1) {
    header("Location: priv8/ididthis.php");
} else if ($row['id'] >= 1) {
    header("Location: index.php");
} else {
    $errormsg = "Incorrect username or Password!";
}
```

can u see what's wrong with my code ? the `$errormsg` doesn't showing when the username or the password is wrong..

`

```
<body>
<div class="layout">
    <div class="layout-screen">
        <div class="app-title">
            <h1>Login</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="layout-form">

            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">

            <div class="control-group">
            <input type="text" name="username" class="login-field" value="" placeholder="username" id="login-username">
            <label class="login-field-icon fui-user" for="login-username"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
            <span><?php if (isset($username_error)) { echo $username_error; } ?></span>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
            <input type="password" name="password" class="login-field" value="" placeholder="password" id="login-pass">
            <label class="login-field-icon fui-lock" for="login-pass"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
            <span><?php if (isset($password_error)) { echo $password_error; } ?></span>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block" type="submit" name="login" value="Sign in"/>
            </div>

            </form>

            <span><?php if (isset($errormsg)) { echo $errormsg; } ?></span>

            <a class="layout-link" href="forgot.php">Lost your password?</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: =1 and >=1 interacts.

Comment: what is your $results?

Comment: what do you mean ? is it ? `($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your error message is inside this block

```
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    if ($row['id'] == 1) {...} 
    else if ($row['id'] >= 1) {...} 
    else {
        $errormsg = "Incorrect username or Password!";
    }
}
```

This means that the error message is never shown because row id will always be `1` or `>=1`.  To fix, move the error message out, like this:

```
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    if ($row['id'] == 1) {...} 
    else($row['id'] >= 1) {...}         
}
else {
    $errormsg = "Incorrect username or Password!";
}
```

Comment: got error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'` when i remove `if`

Comment: you also need to remove the last } , and  put a } before the last else

Comment: @GilangRizkie Syntax errors are simple to fix (especially if you use a good code editor); pay attention to your brackets. The bottom line is the same though:  The problem with your original code is a logic flaw: the error message should not be a sub-block to the `if query is successful` check.  It should be an `else` to that check.